# starsign smartcard : Invalid Length 6c XX error

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard

Developing a desktop application for accessing the java card applet in G & D starsign smartcard.

Getting Invalid Le "6C XX" error For each APDU sent.Found that appending the "XX"(which is Le) with the APDU command and resending it is the possible solution.But i need a direct solution which solves this issue without resending the APDU.

Comment: Please followup you questions mohan.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can append the XX already to the first command, so there should be no reason for the card to complain. But this requires, that you know the exact length of data to come. If unsure about that, try appending 00 instead. This should work for all command returning data at all (for commands not having a response it might cause a 67 00), as long as extended APDUs (allowing more than 256 byte of result data) are not involved.

`Le = 00h` means thatNe, the *maximum* expected response size is 256. So sending `Le = 00h` should work for any command *that is expected to return a response*. If it doesn't work, check the documentation of the chip vendor for the exact response sizes that you may expect, and use the precise `Le` value instead.

Comment: You are very welcome to StackOverflow guidot. Voted some of your answers up.